# Java Handlebars : not using helpers but context, is it possible?

Tags: java, handlebars.java

I'am using handlebars `"com.github.jknack" % "handlebars" % "4.1.2"` for templating.

What I want is when compiling `{{something.foo}}` and the result is `HW` it replaces automatically the code `HW` by its label `Hello World !`. `HW` can be the result of compiling `{{something.bar}}` too.

Of course, I can use a helper to achieve this requirement, like `{{hw something.foo}}` and `{{hw something.bar}}`. But calling the helper every time is frustrating me.

I'm looking for something, in the context, for example, to do this, as:

```java
Context.newBuilder(object)
                    .resolver(FieldValueResolver.INSTANCE, MethodValueResolver.INSTANCE)
                    .combine("HW", "Hello world !")
                    .build();
```

The code above is not working, I'm just trying.

Does someone have an idea?